# mocha - writing tests - should I remember the previous results?

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, mocha.js

I wrote some tests in mocha.

the code is gonna look like this.

```
describe('contract', accounts => {
  it("test1", () => {

  })


  it("test2", () => {
    
  })

  it("test3", () => {
    
  })
  
})
```

Now, let's say I call `function1` in `test1` and check if everything is correct after calling `function1`.  Then, In `test2`, I test `function2`, but `function2` is kind of dependent on `test1`'s `function1`'s changes. Then, in `test3`, I test `function3`, which is kind of dependent on `function2`'s changes. So it's like `test3` needs to know the state of my variables that `function2` did in `test2` and `test2` needs to know the state of my variables that `test1`'s `function1` did.

**Problem 1:** If I leave it like the above, the problem is that, when another developer comes, he won't be able to quickly change something in `test3` , because if he does, then he needs to know  what to change in `test2` too which means he needs to know what he needs to change in `test1`.  This doesn't seem scalable.

**Problem 2:** Another solution would be that I have one single test case and include all these dependent functions in single test, But now, the problem is that I'd need 3-4 tests like this, since to test each path. and each test would have lots of calls/codes. I'd prefer that each test would test each function.

What do you think ?

Comment: Your tests shouldn't be interdependent; if you can't run them in parallel or in a random order, that's a smell.

Comment: This question actually got born in my head because I am writing tests for smart contracts in truffle and it seems like that before each test, I've to redeploy the contracts again and again.